# Do we really need the 'sports' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I noticed just now that there's a [sports](/questions/tagged/sports) tag on SO.

Looking through the questions that use it, it's mostly used in relation to programming software that is *related* to sport in some way, rather than questions actually *about* it (and why would there be any on a programming QA site anyway?).

Comment: No, we don't need this tag. Related: [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128315)

Comment: @TheEstablishment OK. A quick ctrl-f reveals that it's not in the list in that post. Would it be OK to just edit it out of all the questions that use it (while cleaning up the questions as necessary, of course) and hope that a moderator accepts the edits?

Comment: Eh, you've already asked the question, so no harm in waiting for a bit of feedback from the community. But yes, that would be the standard process. There are only a handful of questions that use the tag, so it won't be that difficult to clean up. You'll need to make sure that you follow the other rules discussed in the linked question, though, like applying any other *relevant* tags, fixing titles, and cleaning up grammar, etc.

Comment: Waiting for Pekka to post an answer with a big burn them all type of image...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sorry Oded.  There's no Pekka here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133842/do-we-really-need-the-sports-tag#comment371746_133842)

It was an interesting tag to clean up.  There were some horrible not-constructive/off-topic questions (all closed and possibly deleted) but there are some *very* interesting statistics-related and schedule/bracket-generation related (not closed, obviously) questions.

Regardless, the tag is gone.  Thanks for catching it.  In the future, feel free to update https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128315 when you come across tags like this (if not sure that it should absolutely be gone, then just post an answer and we'll hash it out).

Comment: Nom nom nom moderator eats tags.

Comment: Hurrah! Die, useless tag!